# How to print the multi dimensional array values in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

I want to print the following array named `$all_class_subjects` in smarty template:

```
Array
(
[4] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 5
            [class_name] => V
            [class_order] => 0
            [class_subject_assign] => 0
            [class_added_date] => 1365837028
            [class_updated_date] => 1365837028
            [class_added_staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
            [class_updated_staff_id] => ff8d4a5ea6bf11dce105aa2fa7b959b8
            [sub_data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Chemistry
                    [1] => Mathematics
                )

        )
)
```

And the code which I'm trying to print the array(not all elements only class_name, and subject names present in `sub_data` array):

```
{if $all_class_subjects}
         {foreach from=$all_class_subjects item=class_subject_data}
       <tr>
           <td width="20%">{$class_subject_data.class_name|capitalize}</td>
           <td width="40%">
            {foreach from=class_subject_data.sub_data item=subject key=subject_name}

            <b>{$subject.subject_name}</b>
              <br />
            {/foreach}

         {/foreach}     h

           </td>
</tr>
```

But I'm not able to print the subject names of the sub_data array. So please help we by telling how to print those subject names. Please help me to print only those subject names, other things I'll manage on  my own. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a syntax error

```
{foreach from=class_subject_data.sub_data item=subject key=subject_name}
```

should be (the `$` appears to be missing on class_subject_data.sub_data):

```
{foreach from=$class_subject_data.sub_data item=subject key=subject_name}
```

Failing that just under the foreach loop use `{$subject|@print_r}` to see if you're getting any data. And just before the loop, see if you're getting any data in your multi dimensional array `{$class_subject_data.sub_data|@print_r}`.

When you debug it and everything looks to be working, to print the values, use the following. `from` is the data array, `item` is the `value` of the array and `key` is the key of the array. Hope this helps!

```
{foreach from=$class_subject_data.sub_data item=subject_name key=subject_key}
    The subject is: {$subject_name} and the Key is {$subject_key}
```

A variable in smarty is defined by `{$variable_name}`. See [the docs](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.tpl) for more info.

Comment: Hey thx. Your trick worked, I'm getting the data.But could you help me a little bit more, please. Just tell me how to print those values in proper format instead of using print_r(). Thx once again for your help.

Comment: Within that loop, just use `{$subject_name}` -- Note the change in `item` and `key` (I'll edit the answer too).

Comment: Hey Cumbo, thank you very much friend for your help. You helped me to achieve exactly I wanted to achieve.